# momentjs - why is moment([2020, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0]).utcOffset(0); showing as '2020-01-28T23:00.00+00:00'?

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone, momentjs

I am trying to create a time object which needs to represent this time: `29 January 2020 00:00:00`.

I need to work without time zone in myproject and so I created my moment object like so:

```
let m = moment([2020, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0]).utcOffset(0);
```

When I log the date I created to the console, this is what happens:

```
console.log(m.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');
>>> 2020-01-28T23:00.00+00:00
```

Is it an issue with '00:00:00' time? Why do I have `23:00:00` instead of the desires dvalue?

Comment: "*Construction with an array will create a date in the current time zone. To create a date from an array at UTC, use moment.utc(Number[]).*" from [the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/)

Comment: Missed that! I feel so stupid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Moment.js documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/):

> ## Parse
>
> [...]
>
> ### Array
>
> [...]
> Construction with an array will create a date in the current time zone. To create a date from an array at UTC, use moment.utc(Number[]).

Therefore `[2020, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0]` is interpreted as your local timezone. Calling [`utcOffset(0)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) then *shifts* that number back one hour, thus you're currently in a +01:00 timezone.

As the documentation suggests, use the [`moment.utc(Number[])` method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) to create a date in UTC timezone directly:

```js
let m = moment.utc([2020, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0]);

console.log(m.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.28.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```